# excel VBA if loop reading .74 as greater than .99?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, export

So the problem is I am going through a range and if either of the cells offset to its right are greater than 99% (.99) it is to export that sheet and clear the information. For some reason it is not reading properly and from what I've seen any number higher than 50% it is exporting and clearing. I'm not sure what I have wrong but any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub Export_loop()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim Vol As Long
Dim Wght As Long
Dim LR As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim rCell As Range

LR = Sheets("Summary").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Sheets("Summary").Range("A2:A" & LR)

LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Summary").Range("A2").Activate

Vol = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
Wght = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value

For Each rCell In rng

If Vol > 0.99 Or Wght > 0.99 Then

Call Save_Out
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveCell.Value).Activate
    Range("A3:N24").Clear
    Range("R3:R24").Clear
    Range("X3:X24").Clear

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Vol = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
    Wght = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value

Else

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Vol = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
    Wght = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value

End If

Next rCell

MsgBox "Exports Completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please review your variable types, Long can't hold decimals. look for single and double in the reference documentation or click on the keywork in your editor and press F1. Trust me it's never a wasted time! Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Long as your data type. The Long data type is used for ***integer*** numbers that are too large to fit in the Integer data type.

You should be using either ***Single*** or ***Double*** data types, depending of the level of precision you need.